# Animate FlatList Grid for delete functions

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

If I have a single column `FlatList`, `LayoutAnimation` properly animates deleting an element from the list by smoothly sliding up into place of the deleted item.

If I set `FlatList` prop `numColumns={2}` (or greater) to make a grid of items, deleting an item from the list no longer animates correctly via easing. When deleting an item now, the items in the grid after it fade out, then fade back in with the selected item now gone.

How do I make a multi-column `FlatList` animate deletions correctly?

```
 renderItem({item,index}) {
      return  (
          <ListItem
            item={item}
            index={index}
            deleteTerm={() => this.deleteItem(index)}
            search={() => this.onSearch(item)}
            />
      )
  }

  deleteItem(index) {
      LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
      this.props.actions({type:'DELETE_TERM', payload: index});
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}
        keyboardDismissMode={'on-drag'}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
        >
          <FlatList
              keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
              data={this.props.searchHistory}
              renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
              numColumns={2}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item}
          />
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
```

Comment: how did you solve this?